# Karabiner tap-dance add held, and tapped and held?

Tags: karabiner

I was using the earlier Ergodox and Oryx software, but now I'm working on an Interl keyboard, and I want to set up tap-dance keys, like in the Ergodox.

This is my code for working with double-tap and single-tap. How can I also add functionality for keys that are held down, and keys that are tapped and then held down?

```
{
  "description": "Tilde: double tap -> escape, single tap -> tilde",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "grave_accent_and_tilde",
        "modifiers": {
          "optional": [
            "any"
          ]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "escape"
        }
      ],
      "to_after_key_up": [
        {
          "set_variable": {
            "name": "tilde pressed",
            "value": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "conditions": [
        {
          "type": "variable_if",
          "name": "tilde pressed",
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "parameters": {
        "basic.to_delayed_action_delay_milliseconds": 250
      },
      "from": {
        "key_code": "grave_accent_and_tilde",
        "modifiers": {
          "optional": [
            "any"
          ]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "set_variable": {
            "name": "tilde pressed",
            "value": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "to_delayed_action": {
        "to_if_invoked": [
          {
            "set_variable": {
              "name": "tilde pressed",
              "value": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "key_code": "grave_accent_and_tilde"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```